# Extracting string using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, pyspark

I have a list of file paths and want to extract string that appears after "hone/" and "-"

For e.g if the string is 'abfss://or01@intadlsgen2naprod.dfs.core.windows.net/alicona/hone/ 120009163_6722508_.csv' then i would like to extract '120009163' .

Since i have a list of such strings i would want to do this using something in one line or recursive.

I am trying to do this in pyspark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the regex pattern `/(\d+)\w*\.\w+$`:

```
df.select(regexp_extract('path', r'/(\d+)\w*\.\w+$', 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=hone\/)(.*?)(?=_)
```

I used `_` instead of `-` to get you the result that you want.